# Getting garbage value as my search value in code-blocks IDE

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am trying simple linear search in code::blocks IDE, I have coded like below

```
int main(){
int numbers[5] = {2,10,20,60,40},search = 60,i=0;

for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
    printf("%d ",numbers[i]);
     if(numbers[i]==search){
       printf("Index[%d] : Found\n",i);
       //break;
     }else{
       printf("Index[%d] : Not Found\n",i);
     }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

If I am not using break in condition and if I keep i<= 5 , which is grater then array size. For i=3 and for i=5 I am getting output "Found". Please see below image

[image]

My question is for i=5 , why I am getting "Found". Why it is not "garbage value " ?

Comment: The indices of the array elements are 0,1,2,3,4. Your loop reads past the array boundary by going to index 5. Change the condition to `<`

Comment: `i<=5` -----> `i<5`.... best using `for(size_t i=0; sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]); i++)` ....`printf("Index[%zu] : Found\n",i);`

Comment: `int numbers[5]` declares an array of **5** items. You attempt to read **6** items and the last one (`numbers[5]`) is read from beyond the array.

Comment: Accessing past the bounds of the array is *undefined behavior* - and apparently your compiler decided to store the value of `search` right after the array? (Which is a lucky coincidence)

Comment: `codeblock` is not involved in any way in this issue. It is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) no matter what compiler or IDE you use.

Comment: My question is why it not showing me error or garbage. Why it's showing me "Found" ?

Comment: Because it's *undefined behavior* - it just happens to be that case on your system. Here's your code compiled with GCC 6.3: http://ideone.com/mM4xxq and it doesn't show "Found"

Comment: @SatuSultana - Your question boils down to why is this **undefined** behavior not the behavior you expect

Comment: @UnholySheep please try it by  code-blocks IDE and see my image also, in last index it is showing me "Found". You are right for garbage output it should be "Not found".

Comment: As already commented in my answer. `search` variable is allocated just after `array`, so `array[5]` probably accesses `search` that is `60`, so found is printed.

Comment: I don't get what your problem is - the code has *undefined behavior* which means the compiler is free to do whatever it wants. Are you asking us why the compiler you use (which we don't even know which one it is) has this *specific* behavior?

Comment: @SatuSultana I agree that you got `Found` as the output, but why do you insist that the output _should_ be `Not found`? The "garbage" value could be 60 too. In fact, as others have mentioned, this is undefined behavior, so you can't say what the output will be. And it is pointless arguing about something undefined.

Comment: `array[5]` = `search` = `60` = `Garbage value`.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you are accessing your array out of bounds due to `i<=5`. This check allow `i` to be `5`, but indexes of arrays using [c](/questions/tagged/c) start from `0` to `size-1`. So maximum allowed index is `4`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int numbers[] = { 2, 10, 20, 60, 40 };
    int search = 60;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]); i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", numbers[i]);

        if (numbers[i] == search)
        {
            printf("Index[%zu] : Found\n", i);
            //break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Index[%zu] : Not Found\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I also changed the `for` using `sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]);` which grants that code to auto-adapt the loop to the real size of array, if you change it.

Lastly I changed `i` type due to `sizeof` return type that is `size_t`: the correct `printf` format format specifier of `size_t` type is `%zu`.

**EDIT**

Trying to explain why `"Found"` is printed in this specific case, we can see how are variable allocated

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| array[0] | array[1] | array[2] | array[3] | array[4] | search |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
                                                            ^
                                                            |
                                                            ------------
                                                            | array[5] |
                                                            ------------
```

So when you access `array[5]`, you are actually accessing value of `search` variable, that is `60`. So

```
if(numbers[i]==search)
```

can be seen as

```
if(search==search)
```

That is obviously `true`.

Comment: I know that I should use i<= 4 , my question is why I am getting "Found" ? why not error or garbage ?

Comment: @SatuSultana - What makes 60 any less garbage than 81?

Comment: It is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so all can happen. There is no runtime check of bouds of arrays. So you are accessing a `int` after array bounds that can store whatever value. In your specific case I guess is the value of `search` variable, so `60`...

Comment: @ LPs My question is for garbage why it's giving me "Found". Shouldn't it "Not found" ??

Comment: I don't know how to explain you. Assume array is allocated from address 0. So it will start from `byte 0` to `byte 19`. After `array` you declared `search` variable. So (probably) search is allocated from `byte 20` to `byte 23`. So `array[4]` will be `byte 16` to `byte 19`, and `array[5]` will be from `byte 20` to `byte 23` that is search.- Value of search is 60. So the "Found" is printed.

Comment: @LPs  If I change search value I am seeing same result !! How ever it could be an ans !!

Comment: See my edit. Whatever value you use for search it will be placed in at `array[5]`.....

Comment: @SatuSultana undefined behavior means anything can happen, even causing [nasal demons to fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)